# Dynamic css file Server Error (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, dynamic

my theme uses a dynamic css file 'custom-style.php' which is included through wp_enqueue_style();
This file includes some styles depending on the theme options (colors,fonts,...)

On some installation there is no access to this file. Trying to access the file via the source code gets a "500 Internal Server Error".  Changing file permissions to 777 does not solve it.

**How can I solve this? Is there any other possibility to create dynamic css files?**

Alternatively I could write a function to include this css in the head of the html but this is not the way I want go.  There are some lines of css and I don't like css in html output.

Comment: You should supply more information such as the server this is running on. But it's most likely you have an error in the dynamic CSS file that causes this. Check your server logs as that will show you what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: The dynamic css file is fine, beacause it's running without issues on other installations/server.  I can't give more infos about the server, because there are clients server.  The theme is a premium theme.  Only on some servers the issue is ON.

Comment: Then that should tell you have some invalid server configuration or environment that is causing this.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from the server and is related to the server configuration. You can put your css code in variable and use the file_put_contents function to put your css code into the style.css file.
Like the code below

```
<?php 
$customColor = #fff;
$css_code = "body{ background:{$customColor}; }";
file_put_contents('style.css',''); //First we empty the file
file_put_contents('style.css',$css_code);//Transfer Css code to file
```

I used this method and it was a good solution